# Finding draw_if_interactive() in pyplot.py

Tags: function, matplotlib, definition, interactive-mode

There are multiple draw_if_interactive() expressions in the pyplot module but I can't find this function's definition anywhere in the module.

From intuition and readings, it's an easy guess that the function enables on-demand plotting but where can I read its definition?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is actually in the backend code. The actual implementation depends on your backend. For example the function with the `TkAgg` backend is in `backend_tkagg.py`:

```
def draw_if_interactive():
    if matplotlib.is_interactive():
        figManager =  Gcf.get_active()
        if figManager is not None:
            figManager.show()
```

Same kind of functions seem to be for other backends, they use the `matplotlib.is_interactive` to determine if this is an interactive session and then use the backend specific drawing commands to draw the image.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I was looking for, a self-contained explanation.  :)